# Pick location from google map and save it on android device

Tags: android, google-maps

how select a location on google map or on MapView in my application using a pushpin and save it locally on my sqlite db.

thanks in advance for relevant ans.

Comment: I know, old question. But just a reminder for who are looking for quick solution. You may consider adding PlacePicker into your application: https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible with the native maps application specifically because the maps application may/may not have the ability to pass in information from the map itself to your activity/database.

You may need to just create your own MapView and then interact with that and save it to **YOUR** database.

Comment: hi joxTraex I am searching for same in my question but you have closed it because you don't know. that this is possible with the native maps application specifically because the maps application may/may not have the ability to pass in information from the map itself to your activity/database"

Answer (score 1):

I am nt sure........But have a look at this url

[Using Google Maps in Android](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android)

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful for someone. With Map Api v2 You can:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
```

...

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng newLatLon) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLon).title("Marker"));                
    }
});
```